# Issue in clicking on every element and performing action

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a webtable which has multiple rows. I want to create a loop such that it traverses all the rows of this table and click on column 1 elements of first row, then check inside that an Edit button exists or not. Then come back and click on next element and check the edit button. Then come back and repeat till all rows are traversed.

But in current code implemented by me, it is just traversing the first row and then exiting. Could someone help me with same.

```
    viewDiscussionScope(driver, scope);
    WebElement paginationLabel = WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver, By.cssSelector(".v-csslayout-cvr-c-pagination__header"));
    if(paginationLabel.isDisplayed())
    {
        WebElement table = WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver, By.cssSelector("table.eds-o-table.cvr-c-table--list tbody"));
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr.eds-o-table__row"));
        for(WebElement row: rows)
            {
                List<WebElement> tableCols = row.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.eds-o-table__cell:nth-of-type(1)"));
                for(WebElement col : tableCols)
                {
                    col.findElement(By.cssSelector(".v-label-eds-c-text--bold")).click();
                    WebElement messageField = WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver, By.cssSelector(".eds-o-media__body-eds-o-media__body--top .v-label-eds-u-flexitext.v-label-undef-w:nth-of-type(1)"));
                    String messageText = messageField.getText();
                    boolean editLabel = (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".eds-c-button-set-eds-c-button-set--align-right .v-button-eds-s-is-first")).getText()).equals("Edit");
                    if(!(editLabel))
                    {
                        LOG.info(messageText+" is not editable by the logged in user");                         
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LOG.info(messageText+" is editable by the logged in user");                         
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }           
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `break` statement from your parent `for` loop!

```
for(WebElement row: rows)
{
            List<WebElement> tableCols = row.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.eds-o-table__cell:nth-of-type(1)"));
            for(WebElement col : tableCols)
            {
               // your code
            }

          // REMOVE => break;
        }           
}
```

Comment: Try printing inside parent loop to check if all your rows are getting traversed ?

Comment: or check size of tableCols.size() after finding from row. I think your findElements from row is not giving you any columns for that row. Your selectors are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `break` that need to be removed and you don't need to loop through the `td` if you want to click only first `td`

```
if (paginationLabel.isDisplayed())
{
    WebElement table = WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver, By.cssSelector("table.eds-o-table.cvr-c-table--list tbody"));
    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr.eds-o-table__row"));
    for (WebElement row :  rows)
    {
        // get first td
        WebElement tableCol = row.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.eds-o-table__cell:nth-of-type(1)"));
        tableCol.findElement(By.cssSelector(".v-label-eds-c-text--bold")).click();
        WebElement messageField = WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver, By.cssSelector(".eds-o-media__body-eds-o-media__body--top .v-label-eds-u-flexitext.v-label-undef-w:nth-of-type(1)"));
        String messageText = messageField.getText();
        boolean editLabel = (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".eds-c-button-set-eds-c-button-set--align-right .v-button-eds-s-is-first")).getText()).equals("Edit");
        if (!(editLabel))
        {
            LOG.info(messageText + " is not editable by the logged in user");
        }
        else
        {
            LOG.info(messageText + " is editable by the logged in user");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to find where is edit button located in table you can find its xpath,  does of all edit buttons having same xpath if yes then your problem will be solved in you just need to find by findElements() method and store it into List and to get value of edit buttons  or to check if is available or not  you can call .get() method which will get all respected buttons of same xpath and by specifying index as .get(0),.get(1) or pass it in loop you get his value by .getText() method and check or perform actions on that

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide the DOM of the table you trying to work on, i can help you better.

If i understood correctly your problem here is the solution, also, i strongly advice to use methods for small tasks, which will help you in the long run. Also, the selectors needs a better wraping, also the explicit wait needs a wrapper with his own methods.

try this:

```
 if (paginationLabel.isDisplayed())
{
    WebElement table = WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver, By.cssSelector("table.eds-o-table.cvr-c-table--list tbody"));
    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr.eds-o-table__row"));
    for (int i=1; i<=rows.size; i++)
    {

        // get first td

       clickColumn(int i);
       getMessageText(int i);
        boolean editLabel = (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".eds-c-button-set-eds-c-button-set--align-right .v-button-eds-s-is-first")).getText()).equals("Edit");
        if (!(editLabel))
        {
            LOG.info(messageText + " is not editable by the logged in user");
        }
        else
        {
            LOG.info(messageText + " is editable by the logged in user");
        }
    }
}

private clickColumn(int position) {
 WebElement tableCol = row.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.eds-o-table__cell:nth-of-type(" + position + ")"));
            tableCol.findElement(By.cssSelector(".v-label-eds-c-text--bold")).click();
}

private getMessageText(int position) {
WebElement messageField = WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver, By.cssSelector(".eds-o-media__body-eds-o-media__body--top .v-label-eds-u-flexitext.v-label-undef-w:nth-of-type(" + position + ")"));
            String messageText = messageField.getText();
}
```